# Having Optimizer switch power storage based on Capacities and net load

Tags: python, gekko

I am trying to have an optimizer use two power storages for a cyclic power generation and consumption cycle. The goal is to have it turn off the primary energy storage(in this case electric battery storage) when it has reached full capacity, and then to discharge first until it is empty. The secondary storage is to charge after the primary and discharge after the primary storage. I would like the optimizer to solve as it goes based on the system. I have tried using a series of switches, but it isn't quite working. I know that using if statements are tricky for gradient based solvers so if there is any help that would be great thanks!

```
Capacity = 76.2
EStored = m.SV(value=0,lb=0,ub=Capacity)
batteryeff = .95
batteff = m.if3((Enuc - Cons),1/batteryeff,batteryeff)

#Energy Balance 
Cost = m.Var()
eneed = m.sign2(Enuc-Cons)  #gives sign of energy need for energy storage or removal from storage
eswitch = m.if3(eneed,0, 1) #Turns eneed into a binary switch
switch = m.if3(eswitch*(Capacity-EStored)+(1-eswitch)*(EStored),0,1) #supposed to charge battery until at capacity and then discharge until EStored is 0. Then use thermal energy second


m.Equation(EStored.dt() == (switch)*batteff*(Enuc - Cons))  #Energy balance for Battery
m.Equation(T.dt() == (1-switch)*thermeff*(Enuc - Cons)/(mass*Cp)) #Energy balance for Thermal Storage
m.Equation(Cost == Enuc*1000 )
m.Obj(Cost)

m.options.IMODE = 5
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve()
```

This is the section of the code that I am working with however if more details are necissary here is the simplified version of total code.

````
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad

#Set up basic power consumption data
n = 24
t = np.linspace(0,n,n)
def load(t):
    return  -10*np.sin(2*np.pi*t/24)+40
Load = load(t)
Gen = np.ones(n)*40
def need(t):
    return 10*np.sin(2*np.pi*t/24)+10

#Set up Model
m = GEKKO()
m.time = t

Cons = m.Param(value=Load)
Enuc = m.FV(value=45, lb=0) #nuclear power
Enuc.STATUS = 1

#Thermal Energy Storage
T = m.SV(value=300,ub=500,lb=300)
mass = m.FV(value=.0746,lb=0)
mass.STATUS=0
Cp = m.Param(value=5)
thermaleff = .8   #80%efficient
thermeff = m.if3((Enuc - Cons)/(mass*Cp),1/thermaleff,thermaleff)

#Battery Electrical storage
Capacity = 76.2
EStored = m.SV(value=0,lb=0,ub=Capacity)
batteryeff = .95
batteff = m.if3((Enuc - Cons),1/batteryeff,batteryeff)

#Energy Balance 
Cost = m.Var()
eneed = m.sign2(Enuc-Cons)  #gives sign of energy need for energy storage or removal from storage
eswitch = m.if3(eneed,0, 1) #Turns eneed into a binary switch
switch = m.if3(eswitch*(Capacity-EStored)+(1-eswitch)*(EStored),0,1) #supposed to charge battery until at capacity and then discharge until EStored is 0. Then use thermal energy second


m.Equation(EStored.dt() == (switch)*batteff*(Enuc - Cons))  #Energy balance for Battery
m.Equation(T.dt() == (1-switch)*thermeff*(Enuc - Cons)/(mass*Cp)) #Energy balance for Thermal Storage
m.Equation(Cost == Enuc*1000 )
m.Obj(Cost)

m.options.IMODE = 5
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve()

#plot
plt.subplot(3,1,1)
plt.plot(t,Load)
plt.plot(t,Enuc.value, label=f'Enuc = {Enuc.value[-1]}')
plt.ylabel("Energy")
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(3,1,2)
plt.plot(t,EStored.value, label=f'Capacity = {np.max(EStored.value):.03}')
plt.title("Battery Storage")
plt.ylabel("Energy")
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(3,1,3)
plt.plot(t,T.value,label=f'mass = {mass.value[-1]:.03}')
plt.title("Thermal Storage")
plt.ylabel("Temperature(K)")
plt.legend()
plt.show()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use slack variables instead of switching conditions. Here is a simple problem with two tanks and a total inlet flow of `100`. The inlet flow can be split between the two tanks but the tanks have a maximum volume of `300` and `1000`, respectively. Tank 2 is more expensive to use (like your thermal energy system).

[image: Tank filling]

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,10,100)
t = m.Var(0); m.Equation(t.dt()==1) # define time
flow = 100

V1 = m.Var(0,lb=0,ub=300) # tank 1
inlet1 = m.MV(0,lb=0); inlet1.STATUS = 1; inlet1.DCOST = 1e-4
m.Minimize(inlet1)

V2 = m.Var(0,lb=0,ub=1000) # tank 2
inlet2 = m.MV(0,lb=0); inlet2.STATUS = 1; inlet2.DCOST = 1e-4
m.Minimize(10*inlet2) # more expensive
                      # use tank 2 if tank 1 is projected to be filled

# only one in use, could also use inlet1*inlet2==0 to
#  enforce the complementarity condition
m.Minimize(inlet1*inlet2)

# mass balance
m.Equation(flow==inlet1+inlet2)
m.Equations([V1.dt()==inlet1,V2.dt()==inlet2])

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve(disp=False)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(m.time,inlet1.value,'r--',label='Inlet 1')
plt.plot(m.time,V1.value,'r-',label='Volume 1')
plt.plot(m.time,inlet2.value,'b--',label='Inlet 2')
plt.plot(m.time,V2.value,'b-',label='Volume 2')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

If the optimizer knows that both electrical and thermal energy storage will fill up then it doesn't necessarily matter when they are stored. If you do want logical conditions to enforce precidence then an `m.if3()` statement may be better but may also be harder to solve. If you can charge the electrical and thermal energy at the same time then the complementarity enforcer `m.Minimize(inlet1*inlet2)` also isn't needed and gives a different but still optimal solution.

[image: continuous filling]

In both cases, tank 1 is the cheaper option so it will reach capacity and minimize the filling of tank 2. This may be a better solution for your case because then you don't need the switching conditions that can cause problems. The battery storage will fill completely but it may do it at the same time as filling the thermal energy if the prediction is that battery will fill up during the night when electricity needs to be stored.